# How can I generate a sine chart at runtime using TCustomTeeFunction and TButton?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'd like to generate sine chart. I've used this http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomTeeFunction.html
However it is added at design time. How to use that TCustomTee function only after clicking at Button during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Function in TeeChart is assigned to a Series. Then, you can Activate/Deactivate that Series when you want.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Series2.Active:=False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Series2.Active:=True;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I met another problem. I have something like this inside TeeFunction: y:=sin(x)+g; I assign the value for 'g' in FormCreate but it doesn't go to  TeeFucnction. As a target I'd like to calculate 'g' from DateTimePickers after user action (TButton).

Comment: Looks like TeeFunction only allows 'Constant'. But I need change my chart during runtime.

Comment: It looks like a quite different question. I'd suggest you to open a new question so we can write a proper answer for it.

Comment: I solved it with 'TeeFunction1.ReCalculate' function